# Is there any etymological connection between "whisper" and "lisp"?

Tags: etymology

Is there any etymological connection between "whisper" and "lisp"?

Both involve speech, have an "isp" sound, and a lisp can sometimes be quiet like a whisper...

Although, I haven't found much connecting them directly, except a report that in German:

> lispeln = to lisp, to whisper

And that was from the [The Encyclopædic Dictionary](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ZIIVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA608&lpg=PA608&dq=lisp+and+whisper+connection&source=bl&ots=aR2vED9Fdn&sig=Ma61jHaaWi1voLZ98UNAlkYBa9Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4pry_oLPYAhUG94MKHV6CCQAQ6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q=lisp%20and%20whisper%20connection&f=false)) of Robert Hunter, circa 1885.

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that the two terms have the same etymological root, but they both have an origin of imitative nature as suggested by 
[An Etymological Dictionary of the English Language
Di Walter W. Skeat](https://books.google.it/books?id=jeeGAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA343&lpg=PA343&dq=whisper%20vs%20lisp%20etymology&source=bl&ots=rQX_smKSAv&sig=lBMaLHinZMU7RGEyWdrnHimnGls&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSheOW2LPYAhXGXRQKHVPbAoYQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=whisper%20vs%20lisp%20etymology&f=false)

[Whisper](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/whisper#/search):

> derives from [whistle](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/whistle) from Old English hwistlan, hwistlian (“to whistle”), from Proto-Germanic *hwistlōną (“to make a hissing sound”) from PIE *kwei- "to hiss, whistle," imitative.

[Lisp](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/lisp#Etymology):

> from Old English wlisp, wlips (“stammering, lisping”, adj), from Proto-Germanic *wlispaz (“lisping”), from Proto-Indo-European *wlis-, *wleys- (“rod”), from *wel- (“to turn, roll”)

(Witionary)